# codeigniter sessions not storing cross pages

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

I haven't been able to find the answer to this, and I have searched + read the docs, I have tried many of things. Nothing seems to work. So I come here finally giving up on the search, hoping someone can give me an intelligent answer for a change, maybe something that can help me solve me under lying issue.

Having played with everything accordingly and not so accordingly I have come to the conclusion that there is no equivilant to PHP's "session_start()" running anywhere within my install of CI, this is a core install also. That said.. I know sessions work on my server as I have tried non-ci specific how php.net says to do it.. and they hold just fine.

any takers on what the issue is? Sorry if I sound arrogant above, im just tired, and even more tired of someone telling me "its not right" cause that part I figured out on my own.. and coming to forums I'd hope for help to debunk my issue and get on track not some bs answers..

well thanks all for taking in my rant/question

-frustrated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you've already figured out - CodeIgniter's Session library doesn't actually use PHP sessions. I haven't really used it, but I think it's their own cookie-only based implementation.

So if you're trying to use the `$_SESSION` variable - it will not work. If you want to use it I'd suggest you extend the core `CI_Controller` class (that's easy and well-documented, if you haven't done it) and call `session_start()` in the constructor of your new Controller class. I personally prefer this, combined with my own sessions handler that uses a database for storage.

Comment: not trying to make use of PHP's native session support, trying to make use of CI's support. Yet for some reason its just not working..